# How to Animate a Fab button (zoom in/out) continuously?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, floating-action-button

I Want to create this type of animation on `FloatingActionButton`

[image]

What I have tried

```
public void animFab() {

    ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_X, from, to);
    ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_Y, from, to);
    ObjectAnimator translationZ = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, from, to);

    AnimatorSet set1 = new AnimatorSet();
    set1.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY, translationZ);
    set1.setDuration(500);
    set1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    set1.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    ObjectAnimator scaleXBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_X, to, from);
    ObjectAnimator scaleYBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_Y, to, from);
    ObjectAnimator translationZBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, to, from);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0.0f, 0.0f);
    path.lineTo(0.5f, 1.3f);
    path.lineTo(0.75f, 0.8f);
    path.lineTo(1.0f, 1.0f);
    PathInterpolator pathInterpolator = new PathInterpolator(path);

    AnimatorSet set2 = new AnimatorSet();
    set2.playTogether(scaleXBack, scaleYBack, translationZBack);
    set2.setDuration(500);
    set2.setInterpolator(pathInterpolator);

    final AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playSequentially(set1, set2);

    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            set.start();
        }
    });
    set.start();


}
```

> The Problem

The Above code is working fine Lolipop  and above device but not working in KitKat device

> Below are some links I have tried

- [Animating Fab on click (zoom in/out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261561/animating-fab-on-click-zoom-in-out)
- [ObjectAnimator starting with a frame jump on Android 4.4 (nexus 5) but not in 4.1 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721378/objectanimator-starting-with-a-frame-jump-on-android-4-4-nexus-5-but-not-in-4)
- [Implementing ImageView transition between activities for pre-Lollipop devices.](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-imageview-transition-between-activities-for-pre-lollipop-devices-8b24bc387a2a)
- [How to achieve Transition animation in Pre lollipop devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781205/how-to-achieve-transition-animation-in-pre-lollipop-devices)
- [Material Transitions in pre lollipop apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360268/material-transitions-in-pre-lollipop-apps)
- [Android ImageView Zoom-in and Zoom-out Continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231290/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-continuously)

Can anyone help to solve the problem in KitKat device

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: may be this library will help you https://github.com/beworker/fabuless?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3880

Comment: What does "not working on KitKat" actually means?

Comment: @azizbekian app is crashing because of `PathInterpolator`  and `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, to, from)` added in api level 21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing "Field requires API 21" Studio lint errors for the following lines of code the app aborts  when running on Lollipop.

```
ObjectAnimator translationZ = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, from, to);
ObjectAnimator translationZBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, to, from);
PathInterpolator pathInterpolator = new PathInterpolator(path);
```

As you know, these features were introduced in API 21 and not available to earlier APIs and that's why you are seeing these errors. You can, however, get a path interpolator from the support library using [PathInterpolatorCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/animation/PathInterpolatorCompat).

> Helper for creating path-based `[Interpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html)` instances. On API 21 or newer, the platform implementation will be used and on older platforms a compatible alternative implementation will be used.

I don't think that you will need a solution for the "z" translation. (I really don't see any difference between having it and not, but that could be just me. Anyway, the FAB already has a shadow for the height effect.)

Here is a rework of `animFab()` with some changes to accommodate APIs before 21. 
*Make sure you snag the `PathInterpolatorCompat` from the v4 support library.* First a video showing the code working on an API 19 emulator:

[image]

```
public void animFab() {  

    ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_X, from, to);  
    ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_Y, from, to);  
    AnimatorSet set1 = new AnimatorSet();  

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {  
        ObjectAnimator translationZ = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, from, to);  
        set1.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY, translationZ);  

    } else {  
        set1.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);  
    }  
    set1.setDuration(500);  
    set1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());  
    set1.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {  
        @Override  
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {  

        }  
    });  

    Path path = new Path();  
    path.moveTo(0.0f, 0.0f);  
    path.lineTo(0.5f, 1.3f);  
    path.lineTo(0.75f, 0.8f);  
    path.lineTo(1.0f, 1.0f);  
    Interpolator pathInterpolator = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(path);  

    AnimatorSet set2 = new AnimatorSet();  
    ObjectAnimator scaleXBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_X, to, from);  
    ObjectAnimator scaleYBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.SCALE_Y, to, from);  

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {  
        ObjectAnimator translationZBack = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.TRANSLATION_Z, to, from);  
        set2.playTogether(scaleXBack, scaleYBack, translationZBack);  
    } else {  
        set2.playTogether(scaleXBack, scaleYBack);  
    }  
    set2.setDuration(500);  
    set2.setInterpolator(pathInterpolator);  

    final AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();  
    set.playSequentially(set1, set2);  

    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {  
        @Override  
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {  
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);  
            set.start();  
        }  
    });  
    set.start();  
}
```

Another possibility is to use [AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) for the drawable animation, but that would be a complete rewrite.

Comment: Hey @Cheticamp its work like a charm thank you so much and thanks for an explanation, and if possible can u provide any sample code using ``AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat`

Comment: @Goku No problem. As for `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat`, I haven't worked with it, so I don't have any sample code to share.