# How to achieve push effect on recycler view row of android natively in android

Tags: android

How to achieve this push effect seen in recycler view below the image

[image]

Comment: You can use [zoom in/out Animation on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577838/how-to-animate-a-fab-button-zoom-in-out-continuously)

Comment: check this https://github.com/bfeher/BFPaperButton

Comment: Here is it which you want : https://github.com/TheKhaeng/pushdown-anim-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Chirag answer which is been deleted

I achieved this using. Best part is I don't need to use a third party library

https://evgenii.com/blog/spring-button-animation-on-android/

**anim class:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
            android:duration="200"
            android:fromXScale="0.9"
            android:toXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="0.9"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" />
</set>
```

**code::**

```
val myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.bounce)
view.startAnimation(myAnim)
```