# Simulating Instagram-like action effect in Android

Tags: android

On Instagram, we have very cool action for liking feeds. I'm trying to implement that on my project.

After single-clicking on `ImageView`, it should show the item with fade-in and zoom-in animate effect. I have written the following code:

```
if (!postLike) {
    holder.like_instagram_post.animate().alpha(0)
            .setDuration(5000).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            holder.like_instagram_post.animate()
                    .alpha(1).setDuration(1000)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
            holder.like_instagram_post.animate()
                    .scaleX(5f).setDuration(1000)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
            holder.like_instagram_post.animate()
                    .scaleY(5f).setDuration(1000)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
            postLike = !postLike;
        }
    }).start();
} else {
    holder.like_instagram_post.animate().alpha(1)
            .setDuration(5000).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            holder.like_instagram_post.animate()
                    .alpha(0).setDuration(1000)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
            holder.like_instagram_post.animate()
                    .scaleX(1f).setDuration(1000)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
            holder.like_instagram_post.animate()
                    .scaleY(1f).setDuration(1000)
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
            postLike = !postLike;
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This code is not working correctly. How should I fix it?

Comment: you might want to give a [try](https://github.com/varunest/SparkButton)

Comment: also check this [Animate a Fab button (zoom in/out) continuously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53577838/7666442)